# keyboard not working in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, keyboard, asus, radeon

I have Asus Zenbook with AMD radeon graphics. After installing Ubuntu 18.04 LTs my laptop keyboard was working fine, but after updating and rebooting the laptop, the keyboard stopped working, not even in lock screen. USB keyboard still works. Touchpad also works.

I followed other similar questions on this topic and followed the following procedure:

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-all
```

after running this code in terminal, and rebooting the laptop, keyboard issue was solved. I did multiple reboots later and keyboard was still working. However, when I shutdown/poweroff the laptop, keyboard does not work when powered on again. So the problem is I have to run the above code everytime I switch on after shutdown.

Is there any way to solve the problem so that laptop keyboard works irrespective of shut down or reboot?

Comment: Try `sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard`.

Comment: dpkg-query: package 'keyboard' is not installed and no information is available
Use dpkg --info (= dpkg-deb --info) to examine archive files,
and dpkg --contents (= dpkg-deb --contents) to list their contents.
/usr/sbin/dpkg-reconfigure: keyboard is not installed

Comment: This is what I am getting.

Comment: Sorry I meant, `sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration`.

Comment: I tried it. However after powering off and then powering on and booting to ubuntu makes the keyboard disabled. so the problem remains.

Comment: why I have to reinstall xserver-xorg-input-all again when it is already installed? after i run the command sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-all it says, already installed. but, it solves the problem. So what is happening? Why restart does not disable the keyboard but power off, on makes it disable?

Comment: There was a command to save those settings made by `dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration`, but I can't remember right now. x86 compatible CPU usually don't delete RAM memory at soft restart, so low level devices like a keyboard might remain in memory, but I'm not really sure about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to deal with the problem by running the command automatically on startup. Thus when I power on the laptop, the command is already executed. But the keyboard will not work until I reboot the laptop after executing the command. I use my touchpad to reboot the laptop from login screen. After reboot keyboard works fine.

So, every power on is followed by a manual reboot.

To run the command on start up, create a file `/etc/rc.local` using

`sudo gedit /etc/rc.local`

Then, paste the following in the file:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
apt install xserver-xorg-input-all
exit 0
```

save and close the file. Then make it executable:

```
sudo chmod +x /etc/rc.local
```

Next time after reboot, this command will be automatically executed.