# What is xserver-xorg-input-all and its purpose?

Tags: xorg, xserver

I recently bought a Asus laptop and installed Ubuntu 20.04. After power off-on I found the laptop keyboard is not working. I found online the following command: `sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-all` and the keyboard issue was solved after reboot.

I want to know what the above command did. What is its purpose?

P.S. I still have the keyboard problem. When I power off/on the laptop keyboard stops working. Above command solves the problem unless I power off my laptop (rebooting is fine). I have asked the same problem here:

[keyboard not working in ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1347702/keyboard-not-working-in-ubuntu-18-04)

I ask the question to understand why the above command fix the problem temporarily but not permanently. A permanent solution will be highly appreciated.

I ran more specific command  `sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-libinput` which also solved the keyboard problem after rebooting.

Following terminal outputs are obtained:

```
 sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-libinput
```

TERMINAL OUTPUT:

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
xserver-xorg-input-libinput is already the newest version (0.29.0-1).
xserver-xorg-input-libinput set to manually installed.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

```
sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-all
```

TERMINAL OUTPUT:

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
xserver-xorg-input-all is already the newest version (1:7.7+19ubuntu14).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

Both the commands solve keyboard problem temporarily after reboot. Keyboard works fine after multiple reboots, but does not work after power off and on.

Comment: I guess what you really want to know is how permanently to fix the problem, and you think (possibly correctly) that understanding why this command temporarily fixes it might help. I hope that adds useful context to people who might be able to help (I have no idea).

Comment: maybe same Problem like https://askubuntu.com/questions/1293849/why-does-my-keyboard-not-work/1293879#1293879

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is merely a meta-package, aimed "to pull in the full suite of drivers for the Xorg server". However, in practice, it only pulls in `libinput` and `wacom`.

`xserver-xorg-input-libinput` provides the drivers for keyboard, mouse and touchpad. It is a more modern system, replacing the venerable `kbd` and `synaptics` drivers. This is the only dependency of the package. `xserver-xorg-input-wacom` is merely a recommended package, but Ubuntu is configured to also automatically pull in recommended packages, so that one is also installed by default.

I am surprised that running this command would "revive" your keyboard: once a package is installed, a mere `sudo apt install` of that package essentially will only tell it is already installed, and do nothing else - except setting it to "manually installed" if it would have been marked as "automatically installed (which it probably isn't, by default). It would be good to include your output of the command `sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-all` in your question. That may give a hint of what special is going on on your system.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have added the terminal outputs in the question. libinput also works as suggested by you. However, it is temporary solution. Evryday I have to power on my laptop and run the command using usb keyboard to enable my laptop keyboard. A permanent solution is highly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: The solution of your actual problem is *not* the topic of your current question. You asked what `xserver-xorg-input-libinput` is, so here is my take on that question. If this is OK, then accept this question. If you have a specific problem to solve, put it in a question and we will try to answer that. Do not change the current question after people have answered: this is not the policy of this site. Ask a new question instead.

Comment: I have asked a question for the keyboard problem here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1347702/keyboard-not-working-in-ubuntu-18-04

Answer (score 0):

Installing the package `xserver-xorg-input-all`

would have caused the [package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic-updates/xserver-xorg-input-all) to have been installed, or if it was already installed, caused it be recorded as manually installed.

You can read the above link to see the [what files are installed](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic-updates/amd64/xserver-xorg-input-all/filelist) ie.

- /usr/share/doc/xserver-xorg-input-all/changelog.gz
- /usr/share/doc/xserver-xorg-input-all/copyright

ie. documentation files only (*it's a meta-package*)

It however has a *dependency* which if it didn't already exist on your system, would have been installed.  ie.

https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/xserver-xorg-input-libinput

You can follow the links to see what that causes to be installed.. (it also had a *recommends* but I'll skip that as I don't know your defaults; I opt to --no-install-recommends by default)

*I however don't see the point to your question, unless it's how to look up what's in a package, and what *dependencies* are brought in by packages/metapackages.*

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I need a permanent solution of the keyboard problem. I have to use a USB keyboard everytime I power on my laptop, to login and then to run the command in terminal and reboot. After that I can use my keyboard until next power off/on.

Comment: Your question title is "What is xserver-xorg-input-all and its purpose?" and doesn't mention keyboard. You do mention keyboard in the description text, but the only clear question I see is about `xserver-xorg-input-all` package and what is it's purpose.

Comment: I have asked a question here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1347702/keyboard-not-working-in-ubuntu-18-04